# Optimal deployment of components

Tags: optimization, setup-deployment

I have an optimal resource allocation problem:

Let us say that I have a set of steps that execute one after the other (strictly in  pre-defined order). Each step consumes a fixed amount of memory and cpu capacity for a pre-specified duration. I also have a infinite set of machines to deploy and run this code in. (each step is an independently deployable component). Each machine specifies its max CPU and memory capacity.

Given a throughput rate (rate at which the first task is invoked), I want to be able to provide the ideal deployment strategy. How to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I can decipher from the problem Statement, trying to rephrase it :

Given a Graph G which has a pre-order in which the steps must execute( say S1 > S2 > S3...Sk).
Each of this steps has fixed CPU %age (Ci) they consume and fixed time(Ti) they will take for execution

The Instances of this graph are created at a fixed throughput of t tps/sec (i.e if t =100, 100 instances of this graph are created per second).

We need to allocate the resources to these instances in such a way that all the resources are optimally and fully utilized. (i.e the time delay must be minimized for catering/allocating resource to any request).